# UML and its equivalent Java Code

Tags: java, uml, equivalent

I have drawn UML class diagram. Now, my task is to convert that UML class diagram to equivalent Java code.

I do not want to use any automated tool, which generates Java code from UML diagram.

Kindly provide some pointers (webLink, PDF file , other), which talks about UML and its equivalent Java Program.

Answer (score 5):

[This 11-page PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.94.9170&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes a mapping from UML notation to Java conventions.  For example, implementing cursors as Java Enumerations, reducing multiple inheritance to single, etc.

Here is a 4-part article on the same subject:

[Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jmod0508/)

[Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jmod0605/)

[Part 3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jmod0626/)

[Part 4](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jmod0604/)

Comment: Thanks for  your  pointer. I am adding some more basic stuff : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/769.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an automated tool, the only alternative is to open a text editor or IDE and create each Java class's .java file by hand.

For every UML class, create a Java class.  Add all the methods and data members you want in those classes.

If there's inheritance called for by the model, have your Java classes extend those classes or implement those interfaces.

Did I misread this question?

Comment: Let me rephrashed my question : For instance, In UML diagram, we draw Inheritance from  one  class to other class. then  its equivalent Java code is  Class A extends Class B {  ..... } .  My requirement is I need a web link , which talks about these types of other relationship and its Java code.

Comment: So what you are looking for is a translation from UML concepts into Java concepts, not from a UML diagram to Java code?

Comment: My advice is to just start writing code.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to use any automated tool, which generates Java code from UML diagram.

Then use **Eclipse** or **vi** :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how class diagrams work, then you should be able to write a Java program from the diagram.

A class diagram has attributes, functions and relationships. In a Java class, the attributes are variables and the methods are functions. The relationships in Java are either extends (for inheritance) or implements.

If there are other specific things that aren't obvious you could ask, but you should be able to translate to code from the design pretty easily.

Comment: Finally, I found sometime that  I was  looking for. http://www.coderanch.com/t/443002/java/java/Java-Coding-UML-Aggregation-Composition